# iprev check for multiple ipv6 addresses

Tags: reverse-dns, ptr-record, fcrdns

Can I add multiple PTR records mapping multiple IPV6 addresses to the same domain, and add multiple AAAA records mapping the same domain to to the same set of IPV6 addresses, to let pass the iprev check?

Comment: Sure, why not? Just do it.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I mean, does the forward DNS query return a random ip? If so, if the returned ip is not equal to the ip for the reverse DNS query, will the iprev fail?